# Find a complex matrix that its square is a sum of a scalar matrix and a jordan block

Tags: linear-algebra, block-matrices

Attempting to solve a question from homework, relating to Jordan normal form:

> Let $a \in \mathbb{C}, N \in M_n^\mathbb{C}$. $N$ is nilpotent of index 3.
>   Prove that the matrix $S \in M_n^\mathbb{C}$, defined as follows: $$S=a\left(I_n + {1\over2}N - {1\over8}N^2\right)$$
>   satisfies: $$S^2 = a^2\left(I_n + N\right)$$

This part was trivial - and have solved it. The next part is as follows, which I am having trouble with:

> Let $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}, \lambda\ne0$. Find a matrix $S \in M_3^\mathbb{C}$ such that $S^2=\lambda^2I_n+J_3$.

This was obviously trivial if the requirement was $\lambda^2(I_n+J_3)$, as this is simply a use of the results of the first part.

I've therefore tried as follows. We require a matrix $A$ such that $A^2=\lambda^2I_n+J_3$. $S$ is the matrix that satisfies the first part.

I'll try to find $A$ such that $A^2 = S^2 - (\lambda^2-1)J_3$. I've tried completing the square, and have ended up with:

$$\left(S-{\lambda^2-1\over2}J_3\right)^2-\left(\left(\lambda^2-1\over2\right)J_3\right)^2$$

Which would've been conventient had the nilpotency index of N in the first part been 2.

Would appreciate any assistance / hints. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it trivial by noticing that $S^2=\lambda^2(I_n+\frac{1}{\lambda^2}J_3)$?

Comment: Not sure how that advances me, sorry. Could you explain further?

Comment: $\frac{1}{\lambda^2}J_3$ is nilpotent, so it is just a consequence of the first part, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that $J_3$ means the $3\times3$ Jordan block for the zero eigenvalue (correct me if I am wrong), so that $J_3^3=0$. You should try a matrix $S$ of the form $S = aI + bJ_3 + cJ_3^2$.

Comment: Thanks. I extracted the general form of $S^2$ when $S$ is of the form you mentioned, chose $a = 1, b = {1\over2\lambda^2}$ and $c = -{1\over16\lambda^4}$. That satisfied the requirements. Thanks again!

Comment: @iravid Have you double checked your results? Your answer seems to be incorrect.

Comment: Well, here's what I came up with: $$S^2 = a^2I+(ab+b)J_3+(2ac+b^2)J_3^2$$

Comment: @iravid Nope. The coefficient of $J_3$ in $S^2$ is $2ab$, not $(ab+b)$.

Comment: Oh, I'll double-check again then. Thanks.